# UWP WriteableBitmap DPI Info

Tags: win-universal-app, writeablebitmap

Our application has rendering logic that depends on the horizontal / vertical image resolutions in dots per inch.

This used to be available as DpiX and DpiY properties in the WriteableBitmap / BitmapSource classes:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.writeablebitmap.aspx

For UWP, it's gone:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br243259

Do the properties exist somewhere else now or are they totally gone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For UWP, the properties exist in [BitmapDecoder class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br226176) now. Here is a simple code sample about getting DPI information by using this class:

```
 var file = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/HelloWorld.png"));
 using (IRandomAccessStream stream = await file.OpenReadAsync())
 {                
     BitmapDecoder decoder = await BitmapDecoder.CreateAsync(BitmapDecoder.PngDecoderId, stream); 
     var DpiX = decoder.DpiX;
     var DpiY = decoder.DpiY;                 
 }
```

Comment: Thank you. This works correctly when retrieved directly from a file.